# Expression must have a pointer-to-object type error in an array

Tags: arrays, c, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 10

typedef struct{
    int nelem; //amount of numbers in the array
    int vector[DIM];
}t_vector_int;

int main(){
    t_vector_int vect={5,{3, 23, 56, 109, 238}};
    int n, i=0;

    printf(" Vector inicial: 3, 23, 56, 109, 238\n\nIntroduzca un valor entero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(vect[i] <= n){

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error in line 15 `while(vect[i] <= n){`, I know it's because vect is defined as `{5,{3, 23, 56, 109, 238}}`but don't really know how to chech if n belongs to vect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the member `vector`, not the structure variable itself.

Change

```
 while(vect[i] <= n)
```

to

```
while(vect.vector[i] <= n)
```